# Swift ViewController does not have member named

Tags: variables, swift, core-data, member

OK, I've been through all of the threads that supposedly deal with this problem and none of them seem to rectify my issue.

Basically I have a tableview setup with core data and when I segue into the next view controller I want to pass some data. As you know the data being passed must already be declared in the destination view controller, which it is. But I keep getting an error saying the ViewController does not have a member name nItem (the variable I am passing).

Here is the section of code that deals with passing the data from the table view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "editCurrentMed" {
        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let addEditMedVC : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
        let nItem : Meds = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Meds
        addEditMedVC.nItem = nItem
    }

}
```

And here is the top section of my view controller that is declaring the variable along with the view did load section because that accesses it for when the data is edited.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class addEditMedVC: UIViewController {

    var nItem : Meds? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var medName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dosage: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeToTake: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if nItem != nil {
        medName.text = nItem!.name
        dosage.text = nItem!.dose
        nItem!.time = "Morning"
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: let addEditMedVC : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController.
Shouldn't "ViewController" be "addEditMedVC".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean aToz

Comment: is this (addEditMedVC.nItem = nItem) the line which is giving you error?

Comment: Yes it is the error line.

Comment: change this line let addEditMedVC : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
 to
let addEditMedVC : addEditMedVC = segue.destinationViewController as addEditMedVC

Comment: When I do that it gives me use of undeclared type error on that line. And when I change the last line to say ViewController.nItem is maintain my original error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a non-optional value to an optional property should work as expected. But you seem to have confused your class names.

From your `prepareForSegue` it is evident that the class of the destination view controller is `ViewController`. In your class file, however, you write it is a subclass of `UIViewController` called `addEditMedVC` (which looks more like a variable name rather than the usually capitalized class name).

-> Rename your class to `ViewController`.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your recommended solution? Admittedly I should have capitalized the class name, but it has no effect here I don't think. When you create a Cocoa Touch class it only gives the option to select UIViewController, not ViewController. Even so, changing this in the class file has no helpful effect either.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious. Call it `ViewController`, so it matches the one you are referring to in your `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Hi Mundi. That had no affect. Could I not call it foo and still have it work. It seems to me that's just a temp constant anyhow. The thing that is killing me is I'm using this same code successfully in 2 other apps and I don't see any difference between them.

Comment: Come on. Of course you can call your **variable** whatever you like. You should rename your **class**, not the variable! You yourself wrote `let addEditMedVC : ViewController`: the part after the colon `:` is the class name. Change that to the **same** name as that of your view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the following code:

```
let addEditMedVC : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
    let nItem : Meds = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Meds
    addEditMedVC.nItem = nItem
```

to this code works:

```
let vc : addEditMedVC = segue.destinationViewController as addEditMedVC
    let nItem : Meds = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Meds
    vc.nItem = nItem
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I proposed. Class names in lowercase are discouraged and confusing - it confused you!

Comment: I was just posting the code that worked I selected your answer.